# Functional Testing for Customer Parameter Validation - Rspec / Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I Added customer validation in my controller like

```
def customer_create
  if params[:api_key].present?
    ## Create Customer
  else
    ## Render Error Message in Json format
  end
end
```

How can I write Rspec Testing for above method?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presumably `customer_create` is called from your controller's `create` action?

So it might be sufficient to simply test that action.

```
describe CustomersController do
  it "creates customer if :api_key is present` do
    post :create, api_key: "present key", customer_attributes
    expect(Customer.count).to eq 1
  end

  it "does not create customer if :api_key is absent` do
    json_error = {
                  key1: 'value1',
                  key2: 'value2'
                 }.to_json
    post :create, customer_attributes
    expect(response.body).to eq json_error
  end
end
```

You can test the method directly, if you set up the params.

```
describe CustomersController do
  it "creates customer if :api_key is present' do
    controller.params[:api_key] = 'present key'
    controller.params.merge!(customer_attributes)
    controller.customer_create
    expect(Customer.count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Both examples assume customer attributes hash is stored in a variable `customer_attributes`

Comment: it's not a model validation - I send json error message manually. so how can I match json error message.

Comment: I know it's not a model validation.  I've modified my answer to show how you might test for the json error.

Comment: It's really really nice one. Thanks a lot